# Debian 11: trouble adding an existing user to a group

Tags: debian, users

I made a user in Debian 11 via the GUI. 
But when I try to add the user to a group via the CLI,
it says that the user does not exist. 
The `id` command in terminal does not show the user in question,
but the users section in settings shows the user. 
The user in question was made well in advance of trying to add to the group,
and I can even log into the said user.

Edit: I ran `awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd` command
as suggested in eyoung100's comment. 
I was using the capitalized version shown in the GUI (LinuxUser1)
in the `usermod` command tried all lower-case version (linuxuser1)
shown in awk command's output, and it worked.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of: `awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`  This should list all the usernames created either manually or by the Package Manager.  Lets check for typos etc.  If that's not the issue we'll look at the `usermod` command format

Comment: ty for the command/where to look the issue was i was using the capitalized version of the username ie LinuxUser1 vs the commands output of linuxuser1

Comment: Yes case matters, the other common one is putting the username before the groupname in the `usermod` command  Glad I could help!

Comment: HunterBentley is that new paragraph you've added (starting "_edit: ran `awk -F:` command_" a resolution? If so you should either write that an a self-answer or delete the question

Comment: I wasn't sure how closing the question worked but didn't want to delete it up in case it helps someone else having similar problems. this was my first post on the site.

Comment: The GUI shows an other field (start of $5 (instead of $1) from previous awk command): the actual name of a person, usually with a space between first name and last name: the GUI didn't capitalize anything when displaying. This all happened at initial account creation (possibly by a GUI or not), though AccountsService if installed might keep and use a duplicate entry elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I ran awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd command as suggested in eyoung100's comment.  I was using the capitalized version shown in the GUI (LinuxUser1) in the usermod command tried all lower-case version (linuxuser1) shown in the awk command's output, and it worked.